# Wrong file version in requirement package

Tags: python, travis-ci

A file seems to be outdated in requirements package *synergine-0.0.1.9* when environment is build.

*.travis.yml*

```
language: python
python:
  - "3.4"
install:
  - "pip install -r tests_requirements.txt --upgrade"
  - "pip install python-coveralls"
script:
  - coverage run tests.py --rcfile=.coveragerc -v && coverage report -m && python3.4 tests.py
after_success:
  - coveralls
```

**tests_requirements.txt**

```
synergine>=0.0.1
synergine_xyz>=0.0.1
```

**travis-ci.org** build log:

```
[...]
pip 6.0.7 from /home/travis/virtualenv/python3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)
install.1

1.74s $ pip install -r tests_requirements.txt --upgrade

You are using pip version 6.0.7, however version 7.0.3 is available.

You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Collecting synergine>=0.0.1 (from -r tests_requirements.txt (line 1))

  Downloading synergine-0.0.1.9.tar.gz

    pypandoc not found

Collecting synergine-xyz>=0.0.1 (from -r tests_requirements.txt (line 2))

  Downloading synergine_xyz-0.0.1.9.tar.gz

Installing collected packages: synergine-xyz, synergine

  Running setup.py install for synergine-xyz

  Running setup.py install for synergine

    pypandoc not found

Successfully installed synergine-0.0.1.9 synergine-xyz-0.0.1.9

[...]

[...]
0.31s$ coverage run tests.py --rcfile=.coveragerc -v && coverage report -m && python3.4 tests.py

[...]

  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/synergine/core/simulation/MetaValue.py", line 19, in unset

    del (state[subject])

NameError: name 'state' is not defined
```

The `synergine/core/simulation/MetaValue.py", line 19, in unset` on travis-ci build is:

```
del (state[subject])
```

If we look `synergine/core/simulation/MetaValue.py", line 19, in unset`
 available on [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/synergine/synergine-0.0.1.9.tar.gz#md5=84dfad46c5433a7b5a0672b0d8a6ab61):

```
del(metas[subject])
```

Files are not identicals. Problem is in a travis-ci cache ? How can i fix that ?

Build page available [here](https://travis-ci.org/buxx/intelligine).

Comment: Can you show us your requirements.txt file?

Comment: @ssundarraj requirement file added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discuss with travis-ci support by email, we think problem do not come from travis-ci but maybe from pypi (strange specific cache rule ?).